# How to use openssl to generate a JWT using ES256 alogrithm

Tags: openssl, jwt, sign, bearer-token

I am facing difficulty in signing JWT using OPENSSL with ES256 algorithm. Would be great if anyone can share a command or the arguments that needs to be passed to OPENSSL.

I am using the below which is generating an invalid token.

```
echo -n "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInRUUhLTDkifQ.eyJpc3MiOiI2ZGU3Ni02YTYxLTQ3ZTMtZTA1My01YjhjN2MxMWE0ZDEiLCJleHAiOj1ZCI6ImFwcHN0b3JlY29ubmVjdC12MSIsImlhdCI6MTYzMDk5NzcxMX0" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign AuthKey_Q8KL9.pem | openssl enc -base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr -- '+/' '-_'
```

Would be great, if someone can throw light on the above.

Comment: I remember similar post for a different algorithm as below : How to create a Json Web Token (JWT) using OpenSSL shell commands?

Comment: which is answered by Darren Smith for a different algorithm. Would be helpful , if i can find for ES256 algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

1. the filename of your key suggests it is a `secp256k1` key, such key is invalid for use for the ES256 JWS Algorithm. The only usable keys for ES256 is `P-256` (also known as `secp256r1`, or `prime256v1`). The JWS Algorithm name for secp256k1 is `ES256K` as defined in RFC 8812
2. assuming you pipe the serialized JWS Protected Header and JWS Payload concattenated by a `.` then your command may at best produce the JWS Signature, but not the whole token - i'm assuming that's clear
3. What stands in your way is that OpenSSL generates the ECDSA signatures as DER-encoded ASN.1 structure, rather than a simple `r || s` as proposed by IEEE-P1363 which is what JWS uses.

1 and 2 is easy to handle, 3 you cannot achieve with openssl, you need some other command that decodes `r` and `s` from the DER signature, simply concatenates them and base64url encodes it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filip , for your response. For sure , will try the above and will update you . Once again , thanks a lot. Been struggling a lot on this.

Comment: Hi Filip ,  I have updated the actual command that i am using in the question , which is generating  a token , which i am not able to use . Following are few details : I was given a p8 key and i have converted it to pem key using the below command : openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -in AuthKey_Q8KKL9.p8 -out AuthKey_Q8KL9.pem

Comment: As I said, 1 and 2 are straight forward. 3 is what stops you from generating a valid JWT, simply because openssl does not support generating signatures in the format specified by IEEE-P1363.

What you have above already works fine for RSA-based, or EdDSA based algorithms, but will not be valid for ECDSA because of what i mention.

Comment: So , is there any alternative , that we have for me to generate a valid signed token Filip?

Comment: You asked for if someone can "throw light on the above", that's as much as I'm able to do.

The one thing remaining to do is to transform the DER-encoded ECDSA signature to a format that JOSE expects. You can see how that's done, e.g. in javascript [here](https://github.com/Brightspace/node-ecdsa-sig-formatter/blob/master/src/ecdsa-sig-formatter.js)

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem and found the solution here https://github.com/madaster97/openssl-jws.

he resolve a problem with `r || s` as [filip-skokan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9775882/filip-skokan) have explained  by regex

short answer :

```
$(echo -n "$Y" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign "$key_path" | openssl asn1parse -inform DER | perl -n -e'/INTEGER           :([0-9A-Z]*)$/ && print $1' | xxd -p -r | base64| tr -d '\n=' | tr -- '+/' '-_' )"
```

Comment: This will produce an invalid (and unverifiable) result 1/128 of the time (at random)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 would you care to elaborate your riddle?  Maybe we can improve the answer here!

Comment: This answer is incorrect, because any of the R or S integers may start with 00, or even 0000.  In that case, the asn1parse method will return a hex-encoded integer that is shorter in length (i.e. 62 or 60 hexchars, instead of 64), leading to a bad JWS signature (63 or 62 total bytes!)